# why I have no space on disk? are there some hidden files?

Tags: macos, disk-space

It seems to me that numbers don't adds up:

```
df -ah

/Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5    113G   11G   16G  41% /
devfs           194K  194K     0 100% /dev
/dev/disk1s1       -     -     -    - /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s4    113G  3.1G   16G  17% /private/var/vm
map auto_home      0     0     0    - /System/Volumes/Data/home
```

Looking at this it seems I should have almost 100GB free....
On the other side a disk map with Cleaner One shows me that I use 82.4 GB...

It's macOS catalina.

I'm confused

Comment: There are many different ways of calculating free space, depending on how 'free space' is defined. The Finder and Disk Utility also often show different values.

My advice would be not to use Cleaner One, not least because it's got the word 'clean' in its title.

Comment: Use `du -k / |sort -n` to find out biggest files / folders on your drive.